macos/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The macOS deployment target 'MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 10.11 Flutter
While building a Flutter app on MacOS I have the following warnings:
/Users/fractale/lut_viewer/macos/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The macOS deployment target 'MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 10.11, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 10.13 to 13.3.99. (in target 'nanopb-nanopb_Privacy' from project 'Pods')
/Users/fractale/lut_viewer/macos/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The macOS deployment target 'MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 10.11, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 10.13 to 13.3.99. (in target 'nanopb' from project 'Pods')
/Users/fractale/lut_viewer/macos/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The macOS deployment target 'MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 10.11, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 10.13 to 13.3.99. (in target 'PromisesObjC-FBLPromises_Privacy' from project 'Pods')
/Users/fractale/lut_viewer/macos/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The macOS deployment target 'MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 10.11, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 10.13 to 13.3.99. (in target 'PromisesObjC' from project 'Pods')
/Users/fractale/lut_viewer/macos/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The macOS deployment target 'MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 10.12, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 10.13 to 13.3.99. (in target 'GoogleUtilities-GoogleUtilities_Privacy' from project 'Pods')
/Users/fractale/lut_viewer/macos/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The macOS deployment target 'MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 10.12, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 10.13 to 13.3.99. (in target 'GoogleUtilities' from project 'Pods')

if I open /Users/fractale/lut_viewer/macos/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj I can modify the deployment target to 10.13 and the warning disappears but after a flutter clean the issue reappear. the file is probably generated. How to fix the underlying problem? The target's names are not directly used by me but probably by my dependencies.
